# Find similar record by given string in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have word which is dynamic "sticky9 uk". It might be anything.

I want to find similar record based on two columns
e.g
my_word = "sticky9 uk"

And in my database

Coloumn1 : company_name    = "sticky9"

Coloumn2 : contact_person  = "sticky9.com"

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your table where Coloumn1 like '%<Your Word>%' or Coloumn2 like '%<Your Word>%'
```